# Es recomendable guardar el contenido de una función en un header file?

Tags: c

Mucha gente me ha dicho que usualmente en un .h se guarda prototipos de funciones, macros, variables. pero, ¿qué pasaría si guardara el contenido de una función? ¿Sería una mala práctica?
¿Habría algún problema en tiempo de compilación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesante pregunta. Personalmente considero que es una buena práctica de programación implementar el cuerpo de las funciones en los archivos con extensión .c
Como indicas, el archivo con extensión .h estarían destinados para prototipos de funciones, macros e includes.
Aprendí C después de haberme iniciado con Javascript y posteriormente de aprender Java. Al menos, en mi caso, respetar la distinción entre archivos .h y .c hace que programar en C sea "lo más parecido posible" a la programación orientada a objetos, es decir, contar con interfaces (lo que sería un archivo .h) y clases (lo que sería un archivo .c).
Pero finalmente, como todo, sí es posible hacerlo, cada cual decide según sus preferencias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario. He visto muchas personas que en sus programas de C, ponen el contenido de las funciones en un .h para mantener todo más ordenado (según por mi punto de vista, me parece que sí). Incluso cuando hacen un algoritmo bien complejo en su programa, lo agregan en otro .h para tenerlo separado y así mirarlo posteriormente el código de una manera rápida y sencilla. Porqué tener todo el programa en un sólo archivo, se me hace pesado para mí.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿qué pasaría si guardara el contenido de una función?

C no distingue entre declaraciones e implementaciones. Esa es una distinción que hacemos nosotros por varios motivos:

- Legibilidad: Cuanto menos código tienen las cabeceras más facil es identificar la interfaz de la librería.
- Tiempo de compilación: Cada vez que se modifica una cabecera (por pequeño que sea el cambio), se deben recompilar **todos** los archivos que incluyan dicha cabecera, así como los archivos que incluyan a estos últimos. Es decir, modificar una cabecera provoca un efecto dominó que puede obligar a recompilar buena parte de un proyecto. Lo que más suele cambiar de un código suele ser la implementación, luego al aislarla de la cabecera conseguimos reducir la cantidad de ficheros a recompilar.
- Ocultación de código: El desarrollo de un algoritmo puede suponer una inversión de tiempo y de dinero. Exponer alegremente el código fuente que tanto esfuerzo le ha costado conseguir puede no ser la opción preferida para alguien que pretende monetizarlo. El código compilado, si bien puede sufrir ataques de ingeniería inversa, 
  ofrece más protección que presentar el código fuente sin más en forma de cabeceras.
- Aislamiento: Separar la cabecera de la implementación facilita la tarea de crear interfaces. Una interfaz no es más que una especie de contrato. Básicamente te dice qué es lo que se puede hacer con una librería, lo que suceda por detrás es transparente para el cliente. Esta arquitectura permite sustituir implementaciones enteras por otras totalmente diferentes sin que los clientes tengan por qué enterarse.

Por supuesto, tener la implementación en la cabecera también tiene sus ventajas:

- Si el compilador tiene a su disposición la implementación de una función puede perfectamente sustituir la llamada a la función por el código de la misma... en el caso de funciones sencillas que se llaman de forma constante este pequeño cambio puede suponer una mejora importante.
- Al programar librerías, tener la implementación en las cabeceras permite tener código que se puede configurar según necesidades del cliente de la librería. En este caso la implementación suele tener directivas de precompilador. El código precompilado en una librería estática o dinámica no permite esta configuración.

¿Cual es la mejor opción? Depende de las necesidades del proyecto y de los gustos del programador / equipo de desarrollo.

> ¿Sería una mala práctica?

En base a lo comentado en el apartado anterior, depende.

Abusar de ello sí podría considerarse una mala práctica, pero juzgarlo sin conocer los detalles concretos que han llevado a decidir el diseño es aventurarse demasiado.

> ¿Habría algún problema en tiempo de compilación?

Como ya he comentado, sí. Cada cambio en la implementación modificará una cabecera que obligará a recompilar de forma recursiva todos los archivos dependientes, directa o indirectamente, de dicha cabecera.

Es facil de ver con un ejemplo:

A.h

```
#define TIPO int

TIPO producto(TIPO a, TIPO b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

B.h

```
#include "A.h"

#define SIMBOLO 1234

void otraFuncion(TIPO valor);
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

void otraFuncion(TIPO valor)
{
  // ...
}
```

C.h

```
#include "B.h"

#if SIMBOLO < 1000
// ...
#else
// ...
#endif

void yOtraFuncionMas(TIPO v1, TIPO v2);
```

C.cpp

```
#include "C.h"

void yOtraFuncionMas(TIPO v1, TIPO v2)
{
  // ...
}
```

Después de todo este trabajo nos damos cuenta de que la función de `A.h` está mal. La función tiene que devolver un producto, no una suma... pues bien, cambiar ese símbolo obligará a recompilar **todos** los archivos, aunque su código no use la función afectada.

En proyectos con miles de ficheros, elegir un buen diseño puede suponer la diferencia entre un cambio menor y perder media hora (o más) recompilando ficheros.